# Una matriz de punteros no acepta la cantidad de valores dados

Tags: c

Enunciado
Crear un programa en el lenguaje C para gestionar los resultados de la
quiniela de fútbol. Para ello vamos a utilizar dos tablas:
Equipos: Que es una tabla de cadenas donde guardamos en cada
columna el nombre de los dos equipos de cada partido. Indique la
cantidad de partidos por teclado.
Resultados: Es una tabla de enteros donde se indica el resultado.
Tiene dos columnas, en la primera se guarda el número de goles
del equipo que está guardado en la primera columna de la tabla
anterior, y en la segunda los goles del otro equipo.
El programa ira pidiendo los nombres de los equipos de cada partido y
el resultado del partido, a continuación, se imprimirá los resultados
jornada.

el problema con este  codigo es que luego de que `(MatrizEquipos + i) + j)` pasa de 5 palabras se detiene el programa.
dejo por aqui el codigo para saber en que parte de la declaracion de la matriz esta el error.
lo dejo completo porque en otras ocaciones si lo pongo por partes me dicen qe no declare tal cosa y si esta declaradda olo que paa no agobirr no lo ponia completo :) gracias.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define N 10

void main (){
int i,j,M,xN;
int x,y,z;

char ***MatrizEquipos;
MatrizEquipos = (char***)malloc(N*sizeof(char **));//cntidad de filas
for (i=0 ; i < 2; i++)
{
    MatrizEquipos[i] = (char**)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));//cantidd de columnas 
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        MatrizEquipos[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));//cantidad de celdas de caada columna
    }
}

int **MatrizGoles;
MatrizGoles = (int***)malloc(7*sizeof(int **));//cntidad de filas
for (i=0 ; i < 2; i++)
{
    MatrizGoles[i] = (int**)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));//cantidd de columnas 
}

printf("          SISTEMA DE QUINIELAS\n");


printf("PARTIDOS\n");


printf("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD PARTIDOS\n");

scanf("%d",&xN);


for ( i = 0; i < xN; i++)//llenando matriz
{
    printf("PARTIDO # %d\n",i + 1);
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("EQUIPO #%d\n",j + 1);
        scanf("%s",(MatrizEquipos + i) + j);
        printf("GOLES DE EQUIPO#%d=",j + 1);
        scanf("%d",*(MatrizGoles + i) + j);
    }
}

printf("\tRESLTADO FINAL\n");
for ( i = 0; i < xN; i++)
{
    printf("PARTIDO # %d\n",i + 1);
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("EQUIPO #%d\n", j + 1); 
        printf("%s GOLES:%d\n",(MatrizEquipos + i) + j,*(*(MatrizGoles + i) + j));
    }
}

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)//limpindo matriz 1
{
    free(MatrizGoles[i]);
}
free(MatrizGoles);

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)//limpiando matriz 2
{
    free(MatrizEquipos[i]);
}
free(MatrizEquipos);
}
```

casi todo esta hecho con la notacion de punteros a excepción de la declaracion de los espacios de memoria para lass matrices. lo demas esta asi por peticion de mi profesor.

En la siguiente parte entiendo que debe estar el error, pero no logro saber porqué.

```
MatrizEquipos = (char***)malloc(N*sizeof(char **));//cntidad de filas
for (i=0 ; i < 2; i++)
{
    MatrizEquipos[i] = (char**)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));//cantidd de columnas 
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        MatrizEquipos[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));//cantidad de celdas de 
                                                         //caada columna
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que te faltó desreferenciar una vez en `scanf("%s",(MatrizEquipos + i) + j);` y en otras líneas parecidas. Iría justo entre la coma y el paréntesis

Comment: lo agregué  justo donde dijiste  sigue cortandose a la 5ta palabra que ingreso :/

Comment: Solo almacenas 10 partidos? que es N

Comment: Como vas a reservar memoria para la matriz de partidos si todavía no sabes la cantidad de partidos que vas a tener que guardar

Comment: La matriz de goles y de partidos deben ser del mismo tamaño

Comment: Piensa en que harías para resolver el problema char* Matriz[2][N] o un char* Matriz[N][2] parece que estas haciendo una mezcla rara.

Comment: (MatrizEquipos + i) + j) esta aritmética esta mal (MatrizEquipos + 0) + 1) es igual  (MatrizEquipos + 1) + 0)

Comment: sería char* MAtriz[N][2], segui t consejo de ponerlas ambas del mismo tamaño y he estado haciendo pruebas y generalmennte deja de leer como  en el 5to miembro de cada matriz, hace un raato logré que me aceptara los strings y me los imprimierra de esta manera a,c,c,d (lo cual está mal, deberia ser a,b,c,d)suponiendo que solo habia  metido 4 strings. aparte de eso la matriz de goles solo me imprimia bien el 1er valor de cada fila, el segundo variaba siempre;

Comment: intentando arreglar eso, emepece a cambiar las notaciones o la manera de escribir las expresiones para ver si era por indirecciones y volvi al comienzo, donde se detiene luego de unos cuantos valores agregados a la string.

Comment: porqué  la aritmética  esta mal? se supone que empiezo en el esacio 0,0 lego 0,1 y asi susecivamente no? como si fuera [i][j].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás haciendo las reservas de memoria de forma incorrecta. Fijate que en `MatrizEquipos` solo te entra un único `char` en cada posición de la matriz:

```
MatrizEquipos[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    //                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Te falta un multiplicador:

```
MatrizEquipos[i][j] = (char*)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
```

Otro error a la hora de reservar la memoria es al crear la primera reserva de la matriz.

```
MatrizEquipos = (char***)malloc(N*sizeof(char **));
```

El bucle que sigue a esta instrucción itera de 0 a 2, dado que N vale 10, dejarás 8 posiciones sin utilizar. El problema es que la siguiente reserva es de 2 elementos y ahí si iteras de 0 a N... o has invertido el tamaño de las reservas o el valor de los bucles.

Dándole un poco de forma a esas reservas, deberían quedar así:

```
MatrizEquipos = (char***)malloc(2*sizeof(char **));//cntidad de filas
//                              ~ <<--- 2 en vez de N
// el bucle que sigue itera de 0 a 2
for (i=0 ; i < 2; i++)
{
    MatrizEquipos[i] = (char**)malloc(N*sizeof(char*));//cantidd de columnas
    //                                ~ <<-- N en vez de 2
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        MatrizEquipos[i][j] = (char*)malloc(200×sizeof(char));//cantidad de celdas de caada columna
        // longitud del string 199 caracteres
    }
}
```

... o justamente al revés. El caso es que los bucles deben ser coherentes al tamaño de cada array

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS :)

Answer (score 0):

Solución sin usar llamadas al sistema para gestión de memoria :

```
printf("PARTIDOS\n");


printf("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD PARTIDOS\n");

scanf("%d",&xN);
char MatrizE[xN][2][N];
int MatrizG[xN][2];
for ( i = 0; i < xN; i++)//llenando matriz
{
    printf("PARTIDO # %d\n",i + 1);
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("EQUIPO #%d\n",j + 1);
        scanf("%s",MatrizE[i][j]);
        printf("GOLES DE EQUIPO#%d=",j + 1);
        scanf("%d",&(MatrizG[i][j]));
    }
}

printf("\tRESLTADO FINAL\n");
for ( i = 0; i < xN; i++)
{
    printf("PARTIDO # %d\n",i + 1);
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("EQUIPO #%d\n", j + 1); 
        printf("%s GOLES:%d\n",MatrizE[i][j],MatrizG[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Solución con aritmética de punteros:

```
printf("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD PARTIDOS\n");

scanf("%d",&xN);
char MatrizE[xN][2][N];
int MatrizG[xN][2];
for ( i = 0; i < xN; i++)//llenando matriz
{
    printf("PARTIDO # %d\n",i + 1);
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("EQUIPO #%d\n",j + 1);
        scanf("%s",*(*(MatrizE+i)+j));
        printf("GOLES DE EQUIPO#%d=",j + 1);
        scanf("%d",(*(MatrizG+i)+j));
    }
}

printf("\tRESLTADO FINAL\n");
for ( i = 0; i < xN; i++)
{
    printf("PARTIDO # %d\n",i + 1);
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("EQUIPO #%d\n", j + 1); 
        printf("%s GOLES:%d\n",MatrizE[i][j],MatrizG[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Solución con llamadas al sistema para gestión de memoria :

Definir un tamaño amplio para los nombres de los equipos

```
   #define N 80
```

Leemos la cantidad de memoria que tenemos que reservar(numero de partidos)

```
scanf("%d",&xN);
```

Y simulamos las matrices que nos funcionarían en memoria estática

```
//char MatrizE[xN][2][N];

char ***MatrizEquipos;
MatrizEquipos = (char***)malloc(xN*sizeof(char **));//cntidad de filas
for (i=0 ; i < xN; i++)
{
    MatrizEquipos[i] = (char**)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));//cantidd de columnas 
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        MatrizEquipos[i][j] = (char*)malloc(N*sizeof(char));
        //memoria para cada nombre de equipo máximo N caracteres
    }
}
```

Primero un vector con los punteros a los partidos que son de cardinalidad xN. Y luego por cada partido  un vector con dos puntero uno a cada equipo.

```
//int MatrizG[xN][2];

int **MatrizGoles;
MatrizGoles = (int**)malloc(xN*sizeof(int *));//cntidad de filas
for (i=0 ; i < xN; i++)
{
    *(MatrizGoles+i) = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));//cantidd de columnas 
}
```

Ahora si ingresamos los partidos....

Liberamos la memoria

```
for ( i = 0; i < xN; i++)//limpindo matriz 1
{
    free(MatrizGoles[i]);
}
free(MatrizGoles);

for ( i = 0; i < xN; i++)//limpiando matriz 2
{
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    free(MatrizEquipos[i][j]);

 free(MatrizEquipos[i]);
}
free(MatrizEquipos);
```

Para buena nota, habría que controlar la captura de nombres equipos y por lo menos guardarlos solo con la memoria necesaria(mejor un solo puntero por equipo)...

Ahora que tenemos la memoria creada podemos intentar entender

```
*(*(MatrizEquipos+i)+j)
```

Hemos creado tres bloques(enlazados) distintos de memoria(con malloc) para almacenar el nombre de un equipo, cada bloque se puede entender como un vector(cada elemento esta continuo en memoria).Los dos primeros contiene punteros y el tercero caracteres.

`MatrizEquipos`: dirección de memoria que apunta al primer vector

`MatrizEquipos+i:` apunta al elemento i del primer vector

`*(MatrizEquipos+i)`:elemento i del primer vector que es dirección que apunta al segundo vector

`*(MatrizEquipos+i)+j` apunta al elemento j del segundo vector

`*(*(MatrizEquipos+i)+j)` elemento j del segundo vector que es dirección que apunta al nombre del equipo( que es el tercer bloque de tamaño N caracteres)